# Как сделать градиент с белого на прозрачный в андроид?

Tags: android, цвета

Вроде бы похожие темы есть, но конкретно этот вариант не рассматривается. Между тем, получаю все что угодно, но не переход из белого в нулевой.
Какие координаты цветов надо указывать?

Comment: Приведите минимальный код, демонстрирующий ваши попытки реализовать это. Вы же в XML это делать пытаетесь?

Answer (score 3):

Да так элементарно же, создаем в `drawable` какой нить `gradient.xml` со следующим содержанием:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

Превьюшка:

[image: Градиент]

Comment: строка         android:startColor="@color/white"
дает ошибку (цвет вообще не принимается), 
если         android:startColor="@android:color/white"
то ошибка рендеринга.

Comment: @DolceVita ну так это было указано в качестве примера `@color/white`...заведите данный цвет в colors.xml

Comment: понял. завел.
но в том и вся фишка - так или иначе появляется некий темноватый фон, так как если бы я делал градиент из черного в прозрачный.

Comment: может это какие-то проблемы рендеринга в принципе? сейчас я замечаю что любое изменение цвета вообще не происходит сразу, а где-то через 3-4 минуты (в течении которых я пытаюсь понять почему ничего не работает).

Comment: @DolceVita "некий темноватый фон" это фон самой AS...попробуйте на устройстве или в макете

Comment: ага прочел и у Климова - "Во время установки значений вы не увидите изменений, необходимо запустить пример в эмуляторе или на устройстве" 
Да и на устройстве как-то все не сразу обновляется, очень неудобно работать. А уже после того как давно все работает на эмуляторе, в лейауте в компе все еще старые атрибуты или даже устаревшие jpeg сидят. Непонятно что и когда должно их обновлять.

Comment: @DolceVita даже и не знаю, в чем у Вас проблема с обновлением, в AS вроде все отлично и быстро обновляется...у Вас же AndroidStudio?

Comment: да конечно. ну вот например даже не градиент а изменение файла в папке drawable - как быстро это должно сказаться на рендеринге в проекте? у меня в одном из случаев картинка осталась прежней даже после перезапуска АС

Comment: @DolceVita да вроде как в тот же момент и должно изменится